# Four Directions #19 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

(Resurrecting my series from a few years back. The full answer should address all five lines.)

> To the North, you might measure spots by the ounce
>
> To the East, you might have to know what a glyphis
>
> To the South, you might soon encounter the fastest on land
>
> To the West, you might encounter wings around water
>
> I'm something like a flower stuck over your ear.

Where and what am I?

A full answer would contain references to five distinct geographical places.

Hint #1:

> I wonder what species was Puhania Ahirs's favorite?

Hint #2:

> While searching, you might find a better soup and sandwich at the more recent spot.

Hint #3:

> When heading North, a good engine may help you dodge any challengers.

Comment: Is there a missing space at the end of the East line?

Comment: It's a good question, but I'll let the riddle tag speak for itself

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Worth noting that another user edited the question to add the space and it has since been rolled back to remove it again. Read into that what you will...!

Comment: @stiv - that sequence of edits was going to be my first clue to add, if needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** I did not find out *what* you are, but I have found the 5 geographic places, which technically satisfies your requirements.

This is about

> Conservation efforts/ endangered species in India

To the North:

> Snow leopards (also called ounces and a spotted animals) can be found in the Himalayas, including in [**Hemis National Park**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemis_National_Park). The [Chrysler Hemi engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysler_Hemi_engine) is used in the Dodge Challenger and other cars.

To the East:

> The [Ganges Shark (*Glyphis* gangeticus)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganges_shark) is a protected species which can be found in the **Ganges River**, the largest river in India.

To the South:

> There are efforts to [reintroduce cheetahs to Madhya Pradesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheetah_reintroduction_in_India#Possible_reintroduction_sites), specifically to [**Kuno National Park**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuno_National_Park). The Cheetah is the fastest land animal and the reintroduction hasn't happened yet (hence the "soon")

To the West:

> I read the hint wrong (it's Ahir**s**), so this took me a while. According to Wikipedia, Puhania Ahirs is one of the founders of Bhindawas in the state of Haryana, where the [**Bhindawas Wildlife Sanctuary**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhindawas_Wildlife_Sanctuary) is located. The Bhindawas Wildlife Sanctuary is a bird sanctuary based around a lake, so there are wings around water.

You are:

> From **New Delhi**, which lies smack in the middle of all of these locations. A Deli is also a shop where you can buy upscale sandwiches and soups. And a more recent spot is "new".
>  As for what you are, maybe the [**Lotus Temple**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_Temple), although that is in another part of Delhi.

Comment: While the locations in the four directions match your overall theme, that happens to be coincidental.  For N:  if you say the specific name of what you reference, I can confirm if it is the one to focus on (maybe there is only one, I'm not sure).  For E:  You basically have the answer, just a note of the general "place" works.  For S:  You are correct, but there is a specific location.  For W:  Right idea, but that is not the one being referenced.  Once those four are found more specifically, the geographical sleuthing should hopefully lead to the central location/place.

Comment: Also, this is great work - I wasn't sure the word play and clues would get someone dialed in to the general area that quickly.  Now it's just about getting a little more specific.

Comment: I edited in more specific locations, although that hasn't yet helped me find the answer.

Comment: S & E are correct.  N is very close (both logically and geographically) but not quite there, and W is the right idea, but not the correct place.  The fact that two are r13(angvbany cnexf) doesn't mean the others are.  Especially the center location.  I'm happy to add some wordplay clues to the puzzle, if requested.

Comment: Added one clue.

Comment: Thanks! I think I found another interesting connection between the different places. Unfortunately the hint did not help me yet. r13(Chunavn frrzf gb or n ivyyntr naq gur Nuve n tebhc bs crbcyr, ohg V unira'g sbhaq n pbaarpgvba.)

Comment: r13(Gur pyhr znl abg or nobhg ybpngvbaf, ohg pbhyq uryc svaq bar bs gur (zber qvssvphyg) ybpngvbaf.)

Comment: Added another hint

Comment: Thanks! I finally got the first hint, after learning to read correctly... r13(Nz V evtug va nffhzvat gung gur frpbaq uvag ersref gb A)?

Comment: r13(Vg npghnyyl nccyvrf gb gur prageny ybpngvba/cynpr.  V ernyvmrq gung J naq gur prageny cynpr jrer n yvggyr zber qvssvphyg gb cva qbja, guhf gur uvagf. )

Comment: W is correct.  And the actual pun for the main location is no better :)

Comment: Updated with another hint

Comment: That pun broke me. Good stuff! Thanks for the puzzle!

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for working through it!

Comment: All 5 locations correct.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED 20220310

> Is this to do with the official [State Animals of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indian_state_animals)

North

> Is Himachal Pradesh/Ladakh: a snow leopard (known as an ounce)

East

> Is a state with a river shark (genus glyphis)

South

> Is a cheetah (fastest land animal) or perhaps the Indian gray mongoose of Chandigarh

West

> Is Chhattisgarh: a wild water buffalo (as in buffalo wings) or perhaps the butterfly fish of Lakshadweep

You are a

> Melia moth (which is the name of the flower worn in Hawai’i)

However there are still things that don't fit here.

Comment: You are getting close.  There is a specific place associated with each of the clues.  You are very much on the right track with North, East, and South.  West needs some work.  If you find the places each is associated with, it should help direct you to the overall place/answer as well.

Comment: Also, please note the edit that a full answer is 5 distinct places

Comment: Can you please explain why your proposed answers fit the riddle?

Comment: The locations in the four directions do happen to coincide with your N/E/S answers.  But they refer to specific locations.  It's more about the locations and using them to find what is at their center than it is about an overall theme.  But you are definitely on the right track with the word play.

Answer (score 1):

To the North, you might measure spots by the ounce

> Hemis National Park, the only place which matches both snow leopards and the motor in the hint

To the East, you might have to know what a glyphis

> There is no wildlife sanctuary for ganges sharks so it must be the Ganges River itself

To the South, you might soon encounter the fastest on land

> Kuno National Park, which is the one targeted by environment politics lately regarding cheetas

To the West, you might encounter wings around water

> Bhindawas Wildlife Sanctuary, which of all bird sanctuaries is closest to the Puhania reference

I'm something like a flower stuck over your ear.

> You are th Bahá'í Temple of Dehli. The temple is shaped like a lotus flower; It is near New Dehli which is also how people call a delicatessen, a place where you buy soup and sandwhich - some people call it a "deli"; And I think you mean the name of the faith sounds like Hawaii, which is the place where people put flowers in their ears for cultural reasons?

Comment: These are all correct, nicely done.  Though @xyldke has already received the checkmark.  The reference of the fifth spot was a pun about: ybghf grzcyr -> sybjre bire rne (arkg gb grzcyr ba gur urnq)

Comment: It took me some hours to figure out everything. I started at India, then I went to United States and then went back. I figured someone would find everything first anyway